# Use validations for form feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to provide some help to my users for filling out forms. So let's assume I have a model `customer` with

```
validates_presence_of :email
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => 'must be a valid email address'
```

Now I want to get the error messages that belong to `:email` without actually invoking them. So I need the string "(email) can't be blank" and "(email) must be a valid email address" to print them out as tooltips on my registration forms.

So is there any way to obtain them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer.validators will get you an array of validators, then you can iterate them and get, for example: Customer.validators[0].options[:message].

Comment: Okay, I get a list of the validators with this. But I only can fetch the error message, if it is a custom message. The message is `PresenceValidator` is not in the said array.

Comment: Hmm, not easily gotten. You could use custom error messages for all (that's what I do) or somehow extract the default errors--they're in a YAML file.